# how do i tell resharper to apply suggested refactors in a non-one-at-a-time way?

Tags: c#, resharper

Scenario:

I run the "find code issues" function in resharper.

I go one by one, clicking in the little icon-drop-downs that appear.

For example, a WinForms form with all the event handlers generated by VS2010

- if you don't access class memebers,
  they can be made static
- resharper's
  suggested naming is cleaner (to me)

Problem:

I just spent 15 minutes living the life of George Jetson, e.g. clicking a button over and over again, to get what I wanted.

QUESTION: Is there a way to automate all the clicking I just described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the closest you could get is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for Code Cleanup. This won't do the specific example you gave, but it will do a lot of other ones.